# Head inclination in Unity VR

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality, windows-mixed-reality

Behaviour:

when I bow my head in unity the scene moves with me instead of the camera goes bows so i can see or reach a little further.

Expected:

The scene stays at the same position but similar to the mixed reality portal I can bow my head and reach a little further.

Steps to reproduce:

Follow the initial setup part of this link : **https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/uk_faculty_connection/2017/10/09/mixed-reality-immersive-a-beginners-guide-to-building-for-mr/**

Thanks in advance!